# Regular Expression date validation error

Tags: regex

I'm very new in regular expression and I'm trying to validate date using following regular expression [here](http://rubular.com/r/GA3YNgxeBj):

```
^[1-31]\.[1-12]\.[1999-2005]$
```

but I'm getting an output as "invalid reguar expression"

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong I'm doing in above regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions can't match ranges of numbers, like you're doing with `[1-31]`. It can only match ranges of characters. You would need to match `[1-31]` as `([12]?[0-9]|3[01])` instead—it's not the most friendly thing in the world.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}
```

or

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).(19|20)[0-9]{2}$
```

both will match your date but wont validate it.
I doubt that regular expression is a good way to validate a date due to the fact that you must check between 30 and 31 and also 28 plus leap years.

Probably there is a regular expression which handle all combination including leap years. But I recommend to use the existing function of your environment.

For example with PHP use `checkdate()` or the date class if you use Ruby.

Comment: +1 for `checkdate`, but then you have to convert it to a suitable format, don't you?

Comment: checkdate — Validate a Gregorian date || bool checkdate ( int $month , int $day , int $year ) || Returns TRUE if the date given is valid; otherwise returns FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2}$
```

it can match following strings~

```
12.12.1999
12-12-1999
12 12 1999
12/12/1999
```

Answer (score 0):

I do that, it worked perfectly ...

```
for(var i=0; i<100;i++){
    if( /^([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])$/.test(i) ) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
// display only the range of 1 to 31 and disregards the 32-100
```

Comment: I think that only validates the actual date. If you look at the question, it seems like he wants to validate something like `25.3.2004`. Also, the loop makes no sense.

Comment: The loop is for demonstration, is a test... :)